# How to rotate picture without overlapping?

Tags: html, css, rotation, image

I want to read Exif information and rotate them in my HTML file.
I did like this. And it could rotate just fine, but when it comes two or more picture, they don't give my pictures enough space. Could I let them no overlapping and rotate them?

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<style type="text/css">
DIV.rotate {
-webkit-transform:rotate(30deg);
}</style>
</HEAD><BODY>
<div><p><DIV class="rotate"><img 
src="http://taufanlubis.files.wordpress.com/2008/05/google-picasa01.png">
</p></div>
<div><p><DIV class="rotate"><img 
src="http://taufanlubis.files.wordpress.com/2008/05/google-picasa01.png">
</p></div>
<div><p><DIV class="rotate"><img 
src="http://taufanlubis.files.wordpress.com/2008/05/google-picasa01.png">
</p></div>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a `height` for the division almost same as image's width.

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/mZLQ3/)

Or you can specify a `margin-bottom` to the divisions.

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/nbyKJ/)

Cheers!!!

Comment: Thank you Libin, it works perfectly. Would I ask another question. Because after insert the picture, users could insert another picture which is not the same size, and or text. I tried insert text after the rotated picture, the text is overlapped by the picture, is there a way to avoid that? Thank you.

Comment: In that case you needs to use javascript to find the image's height and alter the css height in javascript.

Comment: adding height or margin-bottom seem like hacked solutions to me.  These solutions cannot scale.  There must be a better way so that scaling is protected across media sizes.